# gradle build fails after upgrade?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, querydsl

I have a gradle file that worked for quite some time until apparently the gradle on my OS X was updated (just guessing, I don't recall previous verison) to 4.3.1

Here is my file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'


project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

configurations {
    querydslapt
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/libs"
        }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'cnet-ofac-app'
    version = '0.5'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    querydslapt group: 'com.mysema.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '2.8.0', classifier: 'apt-one-jar', transitive: false

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.5.0')

    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.4.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.4.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")

    compile("org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7")
    compile('javax.mail:mail:1.4.1')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support")

    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.3")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1')
    compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1')
    compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spock-core'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-test'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
    testCompile("junit:junit")

    // for the anontation processor
    querydslapt group: 'com.mysema.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '2.8.0', classifier: 'apt-one-jar', transitive: false
// for compiling
    compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.1.4")
    compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4")

    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-java8time', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'

}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

//Querydsl
def generatedSrcDir = 'src/main/generated'
task createGeneratedSrcDir << {
    file(generatedSrcDir).mkdirs()
}
compileJava.dependsOn createGeneratedSrcDir
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-processor' << 'com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor' << '-s' << file(generatedSrcDir).absolutePath
}
clean {
    delete generatedSrcDir
}
```

And when I run "gradle clean build --stacktrace"  I get the message:

```
Configure project :  The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.leftShift(AbstractTask.java:622)
    at org.gradle.api.Task$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at build_bh7od1fqn35ousgvitx2a7m2p.run(/Users/davidclark/projects/ofac/build.gradle:120)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
.... FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':compileJava' property 'classpath' during up-to-date check.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)

* Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':compileJava' property 'classpath'
during up-to-date check.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:333)
```

I tried upgrading Spring Boot to 1.5.9 in the hopes that would fix it, but apparently there is a major deprecation of Spring-Boot & QueryDSL so in the interest of time I cannot do that.

I also tried changing this:

```
def generatedSrcDir = 'src/main/generated'
task createGeneratedSrcDir << {
    file(generatedSrcDir).mkdirs()
}
```

to

```
def generatedSrcDir = 'src/main/generated'
task createGeneratedSrcDir  {
    doLast {
        file(generatedSrcDir).mkdirs()
    }
}
```

But that didn't help at all.

Comment: The deprecation warning of leftshift is likely unrelated to the build failure. Similar problem reported here(https://discuss.gradle.org/t/failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input-files-for-task-compilejava-property-classpath-during-up-to-date-check/24197) Consider adding your problem there. You can use the gradle wrapper to use any gradle version you like in the meantime.

Comment: is there anyway to find out the actual build error?

Comment: you can google for "debugging gradle build in IDE". Then you could set breakpoints for the given exception and investigate.